# How to post a youtube link on facebook with link preview (webdriver)

Tags: python, webdriver

I am writing a script to post a post on facebook, specifically posting a youtube link on facebook wall! below is my script, it works but when posting on facebook wall, it does not display the link preview, it only shows that link, this is the picture Is there a way to post a youtube link to show link preview? thank you !

[image]

script :

```
try:
    driver.refresh()
    elemen = wait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@name='xhpc_message']")))
    elemen.send_keys( "https://youtu.be/JGwWNGJdvx8")
    time.sleep(15)
    postbutton = wait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Post')]")))
    postbutton.click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("try again")
```

Comment: I think the link preview is the responsibility of the website (facebook in this case) .. not yours. So, try to post this link manually on facebook and see if there is any preview that appears

Comment: @Anwarvic  I tried posting it on facebook manually and all have link preview!

Comment: Try, using `driver.refresh()` after `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: @Anwarvic it does not work , i think can't use send_keys for this  case !!

Comment: thanks @Anwarvic !! I found the solution !! I put  a space after the end of the link

Comment: GREAT!!, write your answer as an answer and mark it as an answer... it could be super helpful for someone else

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone !! I found that solution is to put a space at the end of the link

```
elemen.send_keys( "https://youtu.be/JGwWNGJdvx8 ")
```